# No default class constructor exist for class, в чем проблема?

Tags: c++, ооп, классы, наследование, конструктор

```
#include <iostream>


class TreeNode {
    TreeNode(const TreeNode&);
    TreeNode& operator = (const TreeNode&);
public:
    virtual void output() = 0;

    virtual void outputObject() = 0;
    virtual int calculateObject() = 0;
    virtual ~TreeNode();
};

class IntNode : public TreeNode {
    int number;
public:
    IntNode(int n);
    void output();
    void outputObject();
    int calculateObject();

};

IntNode::IntNode(int n) : number(n) {} <------- ошибка (no default class constructor exist for class "TreeNode")
void IntNode::output() { std::cout << number; }
void IntNode::outputObject() { output(); }
int IntNode::calculateObject() { return number; }

class BinOpNode : public TreeNode {
    TreeNode* left, * right;
    virtual int calculate(int arg1, int arg2) = 0;
public:
    BinOpNode(TreeNode* l, TreeNode* r);
    void outputObject();
    int calculateObject();
    virtual ~BinOpNode();
};

BinOpNode::BinOpNode(TreeNode* l, TreeNode* r) :
    left(l), right(r) {  <------- ошибка (no default class constructor exist for class "TreeNode")
    //піддерева немає - додаємо листок для виразу 0
    if (left == NULL) left = new IntNode(0);
    if (right == NULL) right = new IntNode(0);
}

int BinOpNode::calculateObject() {
    return calculate(left->calculateObject(),
        right->calculateObject());
}
void BinOpNode::outputObject() {
    std::cout << "("; left->outputObject(); std::cout << " ";
    output(); std::cout << " ";
    right->outputObject(); std::cout << ")";
}

BinOpNode::~BinOpNode() {
    if (left != NULL)
    {
        delete left; left = NULL;
    }
    if (right != NULL)
    {
        delete right; right = NULL;
    }
}


// класи подій

class PlusBinOpNode : public BinOpNode {
    int calculate(int arg1, int arg2);
public:
    PlusBinOpNode(TreeNode* l, TreeNode* r);
    void output();
};

PlusBinOpNode::PlusBinOpNode(TreeNode* l, TreeNode* r) : BinOpNode(l, r) {}
    int PlusBinOpNode::calculate(int arg1, int arg2) {
        return arg1 + arg2;
    }   
    void PlusBinOpNode::output() { std::cout << "+"; }

//

class MinusBinOpNode : public BinOpNode {
    int calculate(int arg1, int arg2);
public:
    MinusBinOpNode(TreeNode* l, TreeNode* r);
    void output();
};

MinusBinOpNode::MinusBinOpNode(TreeNode* l, TreeNode* r) : BinOpNode(l, r) {}
    int MinusBinOpNode::calculate(int arg1, int arg2) {
        return arg1 - arg2;
    }
    void MinusBinOpNode::output() { std::cout << "-"; }

//

class MultBinOpNode : public BinOpNode {
    int calculate(int arg1, int arg2);
public:
    MultBinOpNode(TreeNode* l, TreeNode* r);
    void output();
};

MultBinOpNode::MultBinOpNode(TreeNode* l, TreeNode* r) : BinOpNode(l, r) {}
    int MultBinOpNode::calculate(int arg1, int arg2) {
        return arg1 * arg2;
    }
    void MultBinOpNode::output() { std::cout << "*"; }


// 

int main()
{
    TreeNode* root1 = new MinusBinOpNode(new PlusBinOpNode(new IntNode(1), new IntNode(3)), new MultBinOpNode(new IntNode(2), new IntNode(5)));
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Что у нас тут?

```
IntNode::IntNode(int n) : number(n) {}
```

Так, мы знаем, что

```
class IntNode : public TreeNode {
```

значит, должен быть вызван конструктор `TreeNode` в конструкторе `IntNode`. Раз программист его не вызывает сам, его должен вызвать компилятор. Раз так - вызывается конструктор по умолчанию - без аргументов,

```
TreeNode::TreeNode()
```

Такой есть? Нет. Можем ли мы (компилятор то есть) его сгенерировать? Нет - потому что есть конструктор копирования, написанный программистом, а значит, компилятор ничего генерировать не имеет права.

Что остается? жаловаться на жизнь...

Вот компилятор это и сделал.

См. "[правило трех](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D1%82%D1%80%D1%91%D1%85_(C%2B%2B))".

Comment: а можете подсказать как это написать в етом случае?

Comment: В вашем случае абстрактного класса - достаточно просто пустого конструктора.

Comment: "TreeNode::TreeNode()" (declared at line 5) is inaccessible 
Такая ошыбка возникает

Comment: А зачем вы сделали его `private`? Вы не пытайтесь методом тыка - "а если так - вдруг сойдет? Нет? Тогда вот так? Нет? Ну, попробуем еще так..." - а почитайте учебники и действуйте с пониманием того, что вы делаете...

Comment: Я прочитал учебник, и там был написан данный код, что мне делать, если там не обясняют как написать чтоб это работало, я пишу вам, потому что вы знаете как это сделать

Comment: Какой учебник? хочу на это посмотреть. Как называется книга? Если есть URL чтоб скачать - дайте...

Comment: http://csc.knu.ua/media/filer_public/69/0f/690f16f1-513d-4538-b438-82f1d15cafce/kkpsverstka02.pdf

137 страница

Comment: Мда. Странно. Со Ставровским я сталкивался лет 10-15 назад, вроде нормальный мужик, и на тебе такое... Только вот мне что-то припоминается, что он был паскалистом, что ли... Могу только предположить, что они просто показывали кусочки, не заботясь о том, компилируется ли их код. Ну и пользовались они методами древними, сейчас это лучше делать не так. Например, чтобы делать класс не копируемым, не нужно загонять конструктор и присваивание в закрытую часть, лучше описать их как `= delete`... Возьмите здесь - https://ideone.com/bzb8Oq - полный работающий код...

Comment: Большое спасибо!